# populating values from two different columns in single dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

is their anyway I can populate values from two different columns in single 
drop down side by side eg. ave-avenue,st-street and so on where short forms are saved in one column and value in another column. Thanks in advance!

```
<g:select name="streettype" value="${addressInstance?.streettype}" from="${ParaCode.findAllByCodecat('50')}" noSelection="['':'-Select -']" optionKey="abbr" optionValue="value"/>
```

this is code ,where I am fetching value from ParaCode table , value(avenue) is displayed and abbr (ave)I am saving in address Instance instead of this I want to display abbr-value i.e. ave-avenue and save abbr(ave) at backend –  squerys 10 mins ago

Comment: You're going to need to show what you've got so far and what you've tried.

Comment: by just using groovy i'm able to get values from both the columns but those are displaying all the first column values then below that another column value

Comment: What I'm asking for is your code.

Comment: <g:select  name="streettype" value="${addressInstance?.streettype}" from="${ParaCode.findAllByCodecat('50')}"  noSelection="['':'-Select -']" optionKey="abbr" optionValue="value"/>  this is code ,where I am fetching value from ParaCode table , value(avenue) is displayed and abbr (ave)I  am saving in  address Instance instead of this I want to display abbr-value i.e. ave-avenue and save abbr(ave) at backend

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions one of which is by using closure:

```
<g:select name="streettype" value="${addressInstance?.streettype}" from="${ParaCode.findAllByCodecat('50')}" noSelection="['':'-Select -']" optionKey="abbr" optionValue="${{it.abbr +'-'+it.value}}"/>
```